# Renaming new text note in Nixnote2

Tags: 16.04, evernote

I am using Nixnote2 in Ubuntu 16.04 After creating new notebook and naming it I create new text note. By default the name is Untitled note and I find no option to rename it.

[image]

How can I rename it?

And any suggestions for a better evernote desktop client for Ubuntu 16.04

It is to be noted that everpad development has stopped and no new version has come out for a longtime.